# Image File upload in asp.net framework web application

Tags: asp.net, database, image, store, display

I wast to use an image as a **Fileupload** control asp.net application such that when I click on the image, it opens file explorer. Once an image is selected, the the selected image is displayed. I should also be able to store the selected image into a database. Any code to do that?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Post what you have tried so far, if you're having problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please be specific to the point what you have done so far. But I give you link for the solution.
[File Upload control to upload file and save record in database](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/save-image-to-database-using-fileupload-in-Asp-Net)